# How to use config file in both Node and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Assuming I have a node/express app that renders a list of elements.

For the purpose of the example assume I have a config.js file that has, for example, the port number where I want to run the app, and a list of elements (strings) that I want to render in HTML

```
module.exports = {
    port: 3000,
    el1: "el1",
    el2: "el2",
    el3: "el3",
}
```

How can I include this file fo that I can both use the values in Node, to start express and to have access to the element string so I can display them in HTML

Comment: Maybe try the `require` function?

Comment: use a template engine to do it. tutorial : https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myscript.js :

```
let GLOBALS = {
  port: 5959,
};

// Make config file usable on server side
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  module.exports = GLOBALS;
}
```

Clientside :

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

<script>
  console.log(GLOBALS.port)
</script>
```

Serverside :

```
const GLOBALS = require(myscript.js');
console.log(GLOBALS.port);
```